# Find K biggest numbers in the array

Tags: c#, performance, programming-challenge, interview-questions

I was trying to implement method number 2, from [this article](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-largestor-smallest-elements-in-an-array/).

> Method 2 (Use temporary array) K largest elements from arr[0..n-1]
>
> 1. Store the first k elements in a temporary array temp[0..k-1].
> 2. Find the smallest element in temp[], let the smallest element be min.
> 3. For each element x in arr[k] to arr[n-1] If x is greater than the
>      min then remove min from temp[] and insert x.
> 4. Print final k elements of temp[]
>
> Time Complexity: O((n-k)*k). If we want the output sorted then
>   O((n-k)*k + klogk)

Please comment on the complexity and runtime speed. Can I improve my implementation in that sense? I was trying to get O((n-k)*k).

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace JobInterviewTests
{

    //Design an algorithm to find K biggest numbers in the array.
    [TestClass]
    public class KBiggestNumbers
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void FindKBiggestNumbersTest()
        {
            int[] testArray = new[] { 7, 2, 4, 4, 3, 6, 1, 8, 9, 10, 11 };
            int k = 5;
            int[] result = FindKBiggestNumbers(testArray, k);
            int[] expectedResult = new[] { 7,8,9,10,11 };
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);
        }

        private int[] FindKBiggestNumbers(int[] testArray, int k)
        {
            int[] result = new int[k];
            for (int i = 0; i < testArray.Length; i++)
            {
                //if bigger than the smallest node
                if (testArray[i] <= result[0])
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    //if bigger than all?
                    if (testArray[i] > result[k - 1])
                    {
                        for (int l = 0; l < k - 1; l++)
                        {
                            result[l] = result[l + 1];
                        }
                        result[k - 1] = testArray[i];
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        //Naive way
                        //for (int j = 0; j < k-1; j++)
                        //{
                        //    if (testArray[i] > result[j] && testArray[i] <= result[j + 1])
                        //    {
                        //        for (int l = 0; l < j; l++)
                        //        {
                        //            result[l] = result[l + 1];
                        //        }
                        //        result[j] = testArray[i];
                        //        break;
                        //    }
                        //}

                        //binary search
                        int indexLeft = 0;
                        int indexRight = k-1;

                        int currIndex = 0;
                        //10 20 30 40 50 - > place 33 
                        while (indexRight- indexLeft >1)
                        {
                            currIndex = (indexRight + indexLeft)/2;
                            if (testArray[i] >= result[currIndex])
                            {
                                indexLeft = currIndex;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                indexRight = currIndex;
                            }

                        }

                        for (int l = 0; l < currIndex; l++)
                        {
                            result[l] = result[l + 1];
                        }
                        result[currIndex] = testArray[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please if you give -1, explain why you do so, I wish to learn, not just to get whipped...thanks

Comment: You cannot really ask at SE Code Review for _algorithm correctness_. Be sure your algorithm works as intended in 1st place.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I have a unit test, and I checked my code, that doesn't mean it is perfect. so if you can see any corner cases I might have missed or anything like that, this is what I mean by "algorithm correctness". thanks

Comment: You may clarify that in your question then. Within which test-cases your code worked for example, and you're asking for more.

Comment: /OT Seems you're undergoing a painful interview ;-p ...

Comment: /OT @πάνταῥεῖ I'd refuse to answer any math question as an interview question, this doesn't say anything about how good you are at programming

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks, I now edited my question about O((n-k)*k) complexity, is it better this way?

Comment: @t3chb0t it is a question that Facebook, Amazon and Microsoft are using regularly...this is not really a math question, it is just programming question.

Comment: Questions posted here should include the problem statement, not hide it behind a link. Please include all relevant parts of the problem statement. Links can rot.

Comment: Sure not how I read the instructions.

Comment: @t3chb0t This is a math question to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Store the first k elements in a temporary array temp[0..k-1]

You are not doing that

> Find the smallest element in temp[], let the smallest element be min

You are not doing that

> For each element x in arr[k] to arr[n-1]...

You are starting on 0 because you skipped step 1

Nothing in there about a binary search
Not less operations the with the shifts

This

```
if (testArray[i] <= result[0])
{
    continue;
}
else
{
```

Can be

```
if (testArray[i] > result[0])
{
```

Other than that looks good

Just following what I think are the instructions
It is \$\mathcal{O}(n \times k)\$ as the first k elements are not free

```
private int[] FindKBiggestNumbersM(int[] testArray, int k)
{
    int[] result = new int[k];
    int indexMin = 0;
    result[indexMin] = testArray[0];
    int min = result[indexMin];

    for (int i = 1; i < testArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if(i < k)
        {
            result[i] = testArray[i];
            if (result[i] < min)
            {
                min = result[i];
                indexMin = i;
            }
        }
        else if (testArray[i] > min)
        {
            min = testArray[i];
            result[indexMin] = min;
            for (int r = 0; r < k; r++)
            {
                if (result[r] < min)
                {
                    min = result[r];
                    indexMin = r;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**A bug**

On the array of 10 elements

```
19 8 5 9 15 10 8 2 6 1
```

when computing 8 largest numbers, your version returns

```
2 5 8 8 9 10 15 19
^ 
wrong, should be 6
```

when the correct answer is

```
5 6 8 8 9 10 15 19.
```

**Performance**

My idea was to build a maximum heap of the entire input array (which runs, according to Introduction to Algorithms, in \$\Theta(n)\$), after which to peak \$k\$ maximum elments; this algorithm runs in \$\Theta(n + k \log n)\$. That is how:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace CRKBiggestNums
{
    public class KBiggestNumbers
    {
        public static int[] FindKBiggestNumbers(int[] testArray, int k)
        {
            int[] result = new int[k];
            for (int i = 0; i < testArray.Length; i++)
            {
                //if bigger than the smallest node
                if (testArray[i] <= result[0])
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    //if bigger than all?
                    if (testArray[i] > result[k - 1])
                    {
                        for (int l = 0; l < k - 1; l++)
                        {
                            result[l] = result[l + 1];
                        }
                        result[k - 1] = testArray[i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //binary search
                        int indexLeft = 0;
                        int indexRight = k - 1;

                        int currIndex = 0;
                        //10 20 30 40 50 - > place 33 
                        while (indexRight - indexLeft > 1)
                        {
                            currIndex = (indexRight + indexLeft) / 2;
                            if (testArray[i] >= result[currIndex])
                            {
                                indexLeft = currIndex;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                indexRight = currIndex;
                            }

                        }

                        for (int l = 0; l < currIndex; l++)
                        {
                            result[l] = result[l + 1];
                        }
                        result[currIndex] = testArray[i];
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        public static int[] FindKBiggestNumbers2(int[] array, int k)
        {
            BuildMaxHeap(array);
            int[] result = new int[k];
            int heapSize = array.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; ++i)
            {
                result[i] = array[0];
                array[0] = array[--heapSize];
                MaxHeapify(array, 0, heapSize);
            }

            result[result.Length - 1] = array[0];
            return result;
        }

        private static void BuildMaxHeap(int[] array)
        {
            for (int i = array.Length / 2; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                MaxHeapify(array, i, array.Length);
            }
        }

        private static void MaxHeapify(int[] array, int index, int heapSize)
        {
            int leftChildIndex = GetLeftIndex(index);
            int rightChildIndex = leftChildIndex + 1;
            int maxChildIndex = index;
            int target = array[index];

            while (true)
            {
                if (leftChildIndex < heapSize)
                {
                    if (array[leftChildIndex] > target)
                    {
                        maxChildIndex = leftChildIndex;
                    }
                }

                if (maxChildIndex == index)
                {
                    if (rightChildIndex < heapSize)
                    {
                        if (array[rightChildIndex] > target)
                        {
                            maxChildIndex = rightChildIndex;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (rightChildIndex < heapSize)
                    {
                        if (array[rightChildIndex] > array[maxChildIndex])
                        {
                            maxChildIndex = rightChildIndex;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (maxChildIndex == index)
                {
                    array[maxChildIndex] = target;
                    return;
                }

                array[index] = array[maxChildIndex];
                index = maxChildIndex;
                leftChildIndex = GetLeftIndex(index);
                rightChildIndex = leftChildIndex + 1;
            }
        }

        private static int GetLeftIndex(int index)
        {
            return (index << 1) + 1;
        }

        private static long GetMilliseconds()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int[] array1 = new int[1000 * 1000];
            int[] array2 = new int[array1.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i != array1.Length; ++i)
            {
                int element = random.Next(20);
                array1[i] = element;
                array2[i] = element;
            }

            int k = 10 * 1000;
            var start = GetMilliseconds();
            int[] result1 = FindKBiggestNumbers(array1, k);
            var end = GetMilliseconds();

            Console.WriteLine("OP method in {0} milliseconds.", end - start);

            start = GetMilliseconds();
            int[] result2 = FindKBiggestNumbers2(array2, k);
            end = GetMilliseconds();

            Console.WriteLine("coderodde method in {0} milliseconds.", end - start);

            Array.Sort(result1);
            Array.Sort(result2);

            Console.WriteLine("The algorithms agree: {0}.", result1.SequenceEqual(result2));
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the performance figures for \$n = 1000000, k = 10000\$ speak for themselves:

> ```
> OP method in 1692 milliseconds.
> coderodde method in 69 milliseconds.
> ```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey thanks. Great answer.I'm trying to solve this as I am practicing for job interviews. Your solution is better but think, i will be afraid to write it under the pressure of an interview. I would certainly describe it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in the above code because of which **FindKBiggestNumbers** and **FindKBiggestNumbers2** give different results. Actually bug is there in FindKBiggestNumbers function. Here is the modified code for FindKBiggestNumbers

```
public static int[] FindKBiggestNumbers(int[] testArray, int k)
{
    int[] result = new int[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < testArray.Length; i++)
    {
        //if bigger than the smallest node
        if (testArray[i] <= result[0])
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            //if bigger than all?
            if (testArray[i] > result[k - 1])
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < k - 1; l++)
                {
                    result[l] = result[l + 1];
                }
                result[k - 1] = testArray[i];
            }
            else
            {
                //binary search
                int indexLeft = 0;
                int indexRight = k - 1;

                int currIndex = (indexRight + indexLeft) / 2; ;
                //10 20 30 40 50 - > place 33 
                while (indexRight - indexLeft > 1)
                {

                    if (testArray[i] >= result[currIndex])
                    {
                        indexLeft = currIndex;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        indexRight = currIndex;
                    }
                currIndex = (indexRight + indexLeft) / 2;
            }

                for (int l = 0; l < currIndex; l++)
                {
                    result[l] = result[l + 1];
                }
                result[currIndex] = testArray[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```